# How to set the icon above string in SlidingTabLayout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-imageview, textview

I am using the SlidingTabLayout  to create the tab layout , the problem is , it use spannableString, and the icon is at the left of the string, and what I would like to achieve is icon is at the top of the string

Here is the tab xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Here is the Java

```
 SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab, 0);
```

And in the custom FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
   @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        //return tabTitles[position];

        Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
        // Replace blank spaces with image icon
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString("   " + tabTitles[position]);
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return sb;
    }
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout today and had the same question. Adding a newline to the SpannableString worked for me, so the following modification in getPageTitle will do the trick:

```
SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" \n" + tabTitles[position]);
```